# scala 2.13.5 error: value toDouble is not a member of Any

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below Code works fine with 2.12.10 but fails in 2.13.5 with error:

error: value toDouble is not a member of Any
[ERROR]                   Array(maxval.toDouble)).map(_.toDouble))

code:

```scala
val xyz: Array[Double] = 
  Array(minval.toDouble) ++
  (
    (
      (minval.toDouble until maxval.toDouble by width_).toArray ++                 
      Array(maxval.toDouble)
    ).map(_.toDoubleOption) 
  )
```

Comment: Also note that you could avoid all this by using inclusive ranges `Range.inclusive`.

Comment: How is `maxVal` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val xyz: Array[Double] = Array(minval.toDouble) ++
  (((minval.toDouble until maxval.toDouble by 
  width_).toArray.map(_.toDouble) ++
  Array(maxval.toDouble))
)
```

Comment: Note that you end up with `minval` in `xyz` twice. If  you *really* want to this, then `minval.toDouble +: (minval.toDouble to maxval.toDouble by width_).map(_.toDouble).toArray` is clearer. `to` is inclusive so you don't have to append `maxval`. Also a note that you must have `scala.math.BigDecimal.double2bigDecimal` in scope because you are converting to BigDecimals and back to doubles.